# how to use receiveSelected method in JMS

Tags: grails, groovy, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Hi I trying to use receivedSelected method of jmsService but it is returning the null to me. i am passing messageId in selector.
here is code

```
    jmsService.send(service: "myService", method: "test1",[message:1])
    String selector = "JMSMessageID=PLC-1-53472-1380003663066-0"
    def ret = jmsService.receiveSelected("appName.serviceName.test1",selector)
```

any body can tell me where i am wrong.
or is there any another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The value in the selector needs single quotes.

In your example: "JMSMessageID='PLC-1-53472-1380003663066-0'".